# CSS centering tricks

Tags: css, layout, positioning, center

My favorite equation for centering an xhtml element using only CSS is as follows:

```
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: _insert width here_;
left: 50%;
margin-left: _insert width divided by two & multiplied by negative one here_
```

There's also the simpler margin:auto method in browsers that support it. Does anyone else have tricky ways to force content to display centered in its container? (bonus points for vertical centering)

edit - oops, forgot the 'negative' part of one in the margin-left. fixed.

Comment: Also, left is width/2 - how is that centered? If i had votes left, I'd vote on margin:auto; it's the most reliable.

Comment: why do you multiply by one at the bottom?

Comment: whoops, sorry about that. should be negative one. fixed.

Comment: Oh, and Till - you move it 50% to the right, then back 1/2 width to the left again, which centers it. Think about it for a second, or draw it out, you'll get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stick with Margin: 0 auto; for horizontal alignment;
If you need vertical alignment as well use position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -(width/2)px; Be aware though, If your container has more width than your screen a part of it will fall off screen on the left side using the Position: absolute method.

Comment: What? Like <div style="margin-left: 0 auto;"> ????

Comment: no, like: <div style="margin: 0 auto;"></div>

Answer (score 12):

```
div #centered{
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

seems to be the most reliable from my experience.

Comment: Actually works only with most up-to-date browsers. Almost any version, but the latest one of IE will not handle that correct and even older versions of other vendors fail. Further the questioner has already mentioned that solution, why do you repeat it in your answer?

Comment: Also would like to note on this method that it only works for the uppermost div layer, impossible to use the same method for divs inside divs inside divs...

Comment: it should probably be mentioned that giving the containing element text-align:center; will help fix the browsers that won't correctly interpret margin:auto, but you've got to explicity set text-align back to whatever you want it to be on the centered element itself to counter-act that.

Answer (score 5):

Well that seems like massive overkill, I've got to say. I tend to set the container to `text-align:center;` for old browsers, `margin:auto;` for modern browsers, and leave it like that. Then reset text-align in the element (if it contains text).

Of course, some things need setting as block, and widths need setting... But what on earth are you trying to style that needs *that* much hacking around?

```
<div style="text-align:center">
     <div style="width:30px; margin:auto; text-align:left">
         <!-- this div is sitting in the middle of the other -->
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The equation is great for position:absolute, though - can you think of any other ways beside the ones already mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

Margin:auto works in all browsers as long as you make sure IE is in standards mode.

It's more picky than others and requires your doctype to be the very first in your document, which means no whitespace (space, tabs or linefeeds) before it.

If you do that, margin:auto is the way to go! :)

Comment: Also, IE chokes if you are using XHTML and use an XML declaration.

Answer (score 1):

just a note that the margin:auto; method only works if the browser can calculate the width of the item to be centered and the width of the parent container.  in many cases setting width:auto; works, but in some it does not.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute positioning with 50% approach has the severe side effect that if the browser window is narrower then the element then some of the content will appear off the left side of the browser - with no way to scroll to it.

Stick to auto margins - they are far more reliable.

If you are working in Standards mode (which you should be) then they are supported in all the browsers you are likely to care about.

You can use the text-align hack if you really need to support Internet Explorer 5.5 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a handy bookmark for CSS tricks

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/

Contains [lots](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=CenteringBlockElement) [of](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=CenteringAnImage) [centering](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=CenteringTextVertically) tricks too.

Answer (score -1):

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
#container {
    width: 770px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

This works nicely in all the usual browsers. As already mentioned `margin: 0 auto;` won't work in all semi-current versions of IE.

Answer (score -2):

Try this; don't know if it works in IE, works fine in Fx though. It centers a DIV block on the page using CSS only (no JavaScript), no margin-auto and the text within the DIV block is still left aligned. I'm just trying to find out if vertical-centering could work that way, too, but so far without success.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Center Example</title>
<style>
.center {
   clear:both;
   width:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
}
.center .helper {
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   left:50%;
}
.center .helper .content {
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   right:50%;
   border:thin solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
   <div class="helper">
      <div class="content">Centered on the page<br>and left aligned!</div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: eh, too tag soupy - the extra 'helper' and 'center' divs doesn't add any semantic value. This is what we're trying to get away from - xhtml is for content markup, not content layout.